Diagnostic setting Azure
Getting blank value for Eventhub and loganalyticsworkspace even if there is value in azure portal help me trouble shoot.
$resources = Get-AzResource

# Iterate through each resource and get diagnostic settings
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    $resourceName = $resource.Name
    $resourceGroup = $resource.ResourceGroupName
    $resourceType = $resource.ResourceType

    # Get diagnostic settings for the resource
    $diagnosticSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $resource.Id

    # Print the diagnostic settings
    Write-Host "Resource: $resourceName ($resourceType) in $resourceGroup"
    foreach ($setting in $diagnosticSettings) {
        Write-Host "  - Diagnostic Setting Name: $($setting.Name)"
        Write-Host "  - Event Hub: $($setting.Eventhub)"
        Write-Host "  - Log Analytics workspace: $($setting.LogAnalyticsworkspace)"

}}

Getting blank value for Eventhub and loganalyticsworkspace even if there is value in azure portal help me trouble shoot.
$resources = Get-AzResource

# Iterate through each resource and get diagnostic settings
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    $resourceName = $resource.Name
    $resourceGroup = $resource.ResourceGroupName
    $resourceType = $resource.ResourceType

    # Get diagnostic settings for the resource
    $diagnosticSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $resource.Id

    # Print the diagnostic settings
    Write-Host "Resource: $resourceName ($resourceType) in $resourceGroup"
    foreach ($setting in $diagnosticSettings) {
        Write-Host "  - Diagnostic Setting Name: $($setting.Name)"
        Write-Host "  - Event Hub: $($setting.Eventhub)"
        Write-Host "  - Log Analytics workspace: $($setting.LogAnalyticsworkspace)"

}}


Try : $diagnosticSettings | format-List and $diagnosticSettings | Foreach { $_ | Format-List}

As suggested by @jdweng, you can use Format-list PowerShell property to extract all the output properties from the diagnostic settings as shown below.

Even after executing this, I was able to view only the empty value in event hub name.
When it comes to log analytics workspace, it is possible to retrieve the workspace ID but not the name actually.
In order to achieve your requirement, I have used an operator called
-Split available in PowerShell as detailed below.
$resources = Get-AzResource
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    $resourceName = $resource.Name
    $resourceGroup = $resource.ResourceGroupName
    $resourceType = $resource.ResourceType

    $diagnosticSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $resource.Id
    $diagnosticSettings | Foreach { $_ | Format-List}
Write-Host "Resource: $resourceName ($resourceType) in $resourceGroup"
    foreach ($setting in $diagnosticSettings) {
        Write-Host "  - Diagnostic Setting Name: $($setting.Name)"
        Write-Host "  - Log Analytics workspace: $($setting.WorkspaceId)"
        Write-Host "  - Event Hub: $($setting.Id)"
        $splitby = $($setting.Id) -split '/'
        $indexing = [Array]::IndexOf($splitby, 'namespaces')
        if ($indexing -ne -1 -and $indexing + 1 -lt $splitby.Length) {
           $eventHub = $splitby[$indexing + 1]
        Write-Host "Event Hub: $eventHub"
        }
}
}

Output:

